# calling application prototype js function from rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototypejs, rjs

Is it possible to call an application level prototype JavaScript function from rjs? I wanna call a function to perform certain tasks after my ajax call. How am i supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your RJS template:

```
page.call( "functionName", 1, "something", "whatever" )
```